# How to add sidebar closing animation?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I created a sidebar menu with the help of react and tailwindcss.

When the user clicks on the hamburger icon (menu), the sidebar appears with a slight animation as it appears from left to right. I'm currently trying to do the same animation after the user leaves the sidebar, in the reverse direction (sidebar disappearing from right to left), but it honestly doesn't work for me. I've tried many things, but it seems like something in the code itself is stopping such an animation from working.

Can you take a look at the code and try to explain to me the best way to achieve this effect and the goal I set for myself?

This is my react Menu component:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";

const Menu = ({ sidebarOpen, toggleSidebar }) => {
    const containerRef = useRef(null);
    const sidebarRef = useRef(null);
    const [animationComplete, setAnimationComplete] = useState(false);

    const handleToggleSidebar = () => {
        if (!sidebarOpen) {
            setAnimationComplete(false);
        }
        toggleSidebar(!sidebarOpen);
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (sidebarOpen) {
            document.body.classList.add("sidebar-open");
            document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
        } else {
            document.body.classList.remove("sidebar-open");
            document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
        }
    }, [sidebarOpen]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (sidebarOpen && containerRef.current && !animationComplete) {
            const sidebarElement = sidebarRef.current;
            sidebarElement.style.transform = "translateX(-100%)";
            sidebarElement.style.transition = "transform 0s";
            requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                sidebarElement.style.transform = "translateX(0)";
                sidebarElement.style.transition = "transform 0.5s";
                setAnimationComplete(true);
            });
        }
    }, [sidebarOpen, animationComplete]);

    return (
        <div className="fixed bottom-0 left-0 w-full bg-white z-50 border-t-1 border-green-900">
            <div className="h-[60px] flex items-center justify-between">

                <div className="flex items-center ml-4">
                    <div
                        ref={containerRef}
                        className="cursor-pointer p-3"
                        onClick={handleToggleSidebar}
                    >
                        <div className={`h-1 w-6 bg-green-700 rounded mb-1 ${sidebarOpen ? 'opacity-0' : ''}`}></div>
                        <div className={`h-1 w-6 bg-green-700 rounded mb-1 ${sidebarOpen ? 'opacity-0' : ''}`}></div>
                        <div className={`h-1 w-6 bg-green-700 rounded ${sidebarOpen ? 'opacity-0' : ''}`}></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            {sidebarOpen && (
                <>
                    <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 z-0 bg-gray-700 opacity-50" onClick={() => toggleSidebar(false)}></div>
                    <div ref={sidebarRef} className="fixed top-0 left-0 bottom-0 z-10 w-full max-w-[20rem] p-4 bg-white shadow-xl shadow-blue-gray-900/5">
                        <Sidebar />
                    </div>
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Menu;
```

This is custom css sidebar-open:

```
body.sidebar-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is not relevant at all, but you can also take a look into my Sidebar component (since its mentioned in the Menu component:

```
function scrollToTop() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

const Sidebar = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(0);
    const [openAlert, setOpenAlert] = React.useState(true);

    const handleOpen = (value) => {
        setOpen(open === value ? 0 : value);
    };

    return (
        <Card ref={ref} className="fixed top-0 left-0 h-[calc(100vh-2rem)] w-full max-w-[20rem] p-4 shadow-xl shadow-blue-gray-900/5 overflow-y-auto">
         
            <List>
                <Accordion
                    open={open === 1}
                    icon={
                        <ChevronDownIcon
                            strokeWidth={2.5}
                            className={`mx-auto h-4 w-4 transition-transform ${open === 1 ? "rotate-180" : ""}`}
                        />
                    }
                >
                    <Link to="/home" onClick={scrollToTop}>
                        <ListItem className="focus:bg-green-50 hover:bg-green-50">
                                <ListItemPrefix>
                                    <HomeIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-green-900" />
                                </ListItemPrefix>
                                <Typography color="blue-gray" className="mr-auto font-normal">
                                    Home
                                </Typography>
                        </ListItem>
                    </Link>

                    <ListItem className="p-0 focus:bg-green-50 hover:bg-green-50" selected={open === 1}>
                        <AccordionHeader onClick={() => handleOpen(1)} className="border-b-0 p-3">
                            <ListItemPrefix>
                                <PresentationChartBarIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-green-900" />
                            </ListItemPrefix>
                            <Typography color="blue-gray" className="mr-auto font-normal">
                                Dashboard
                            </Typography>
                        </AccordionHeader>
                    </ListItem>

                    <AccordionBody className="py-1">
                        <List className="p-0">
                            <Link to="/balance" onClick={scrollToTop}>
                                <ListItem className="focus:bg-green-50 hover:bg-green-50">
                                    <ListItemPrefix>
                                        <ChevronRightIcon strokeWidth={3} className="h-3 w-5" />
                                    </ListItemPrefix>
                                    Balance
                                </ListItem>
                            </Link>

etc...
```

NOTE: I cut some irrelevant code for simplicity and that's why I have some extra tailwindcss properties in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your animation is not playing because you are removing the CSS class from the HTML when you add a CSS class it adds its properties as well so the animation would be played but on removing the class it got removed from DOM so it has no access to its properties.

**Solution** Rather than manipulating DOM directly you can add a class on your parent sidebar that must be toggled. `${sidebaropen}?"classname to show sidebar":"classname to hide sidebar"`
Remember there are certain properties in CSS that allow animation.

If you still find some issues share the link to the Git repo or something online code editor where we can solve this.